# Publication-Quality Polar Plot Figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, polar-coordinates

I am trying to produce a publication-quality polar plot that slightly mimics this plot:

https://www.nature.com/articles/srep34736/figures/3

The data I am showing here are a bit different -- I'm sorting by interaction (N/S/E/W) and interaction type (color). My plot currently looks pretty mediocre, does anyone have any polarplot tips? Some things that I can think straight off the top of my head but haven't found the solution:

1) Remove the 'ticks' that go N/S/E/W, either entirely or replacing them with ticks on the 45s, however, maintaining the plot labels on N/S/E/W!

2) Be able to customize where the theta labels appear for when data overlaps the labels

3) Prettier colors and implementation on the graph?

4) Change the shape of the outermost circle to a regular octagon or other shape with n-sides?

```
#Bobby Hollingsworth, VTech/Harvard University
#Bevan-Brown Lab, VTech Department of Biochemistry

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show, rc

############################################################
#User Input

#Total number of frames analyzed
frames = 2501.0

#Ener Data for residue 1
resname1 = 'D'
backbone1 = 0
hbond1 = 0
polar1 = 78
hydrophobic1 = 0
aromatic1 = 0

#Ener Data for residue 2
resname2 = 'S'
backbone2 = 776
hbond2 = 1000
polar2 = 2418
hydrophobic2 = 0
aromatic2 = 0

#Ener Data for residue 3
resname3 = 'N'
backbone3 = 1439
hbond3 = 688
polar3 =  1000
hydrophobic3 = 0
aromatic3 = 0

#Ener Data for residue 4
resname4 = 'G'
backbone4 = 2335
hbond4 = 932
polar4 = 0
hydrophobic4 = 0
aromatic4 = 0

####################################################

b1 = backbone1/frames
hb1 = hbond1/frames
p1 = polar1/frames
hy1 = hydrophobic1/frames
a1 = aromatic1/frames


b2 = backbone2/frames
hb2 = hbond2/frames
p2 = polar2/frames
hy2 = hydrophobic2/frames
a2 = aromatic2/frames

b3 = backbone3/frames
hb3 = hbond3/frames
p3 = polar3/frames
hy3 = hydrophobic3/frames
a3 = aromatic3/frames

b4 = backbone4/frames
hb4 = hbond4/frames
p4 = polar4/frames
hy4 = hydrophobic4/frames
a4 = aromatic4/frames

######################################################
#Graph settings

#Figure Size and positioning of labels on axes
fig = figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_axes([.1, .1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)

N = 24
theta = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/N)

#Radii and width of each individual slice
radii = [b1, hy1, a1, 0, hb2, p2, b2, hy2, a2, 0, hb3, p3, b3, hy3, a3, 0, hb4, p4, b4, hy3, a4, 0, hb1, p1]
width = 2*np.pi/N

#X and Y tick size

rc('xtick', labelsize=15)
rc('ytick', labelsize=15)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1])
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['0.2','0.4','0.6','0.8',''])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([np.pi/4, 3*np.pi/4, 5*np.pi/4, 7*np.pi/4])
#ax.xaxis.set_ticks([0, np.pi/2, np.pi, 3*np.pi/2])
#ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([resname1,resname2,resname3,resname4])
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['','','',''])
ax.grid(color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.2)

#FIX COLORATION, ODD AXIS, ODD LABELS, THEN DONE!
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0,  color=['#003366', '#CCCC99', '#666699', 'white', '#808080', '#666699'], alpha=.7)

show()
```

Comment: You should probably check out the Seaborne package for such a complex graph, it will be far easier than matplotlib

Comment: You have 4 different question here. 1) and 2) are modifications to a plot, which can be implemented. 3) is complete subjective and cannot be answered. 4) is a completely different question and certainly not easy.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest feedback on appearance, while subjective, is helpful for designing figures. The only way to really get better appearance is to get feedback, iterate, and try different features--since I don't know very much on python functionality it's really helpful to get critique on here. For example, Matt's suggestion to add seaborne improved the aesthetic a ton!